# Open jupyter notebook from .py in pycharm

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2021.2.3 pro.

Is it possible to open a .py file as a jupyter notebook from within pycharm?

In the classical jupyter notebook, it is possible to open a .py file as a notebook and work with it like with a classical .ipynb (adding markdown etc.).

This allows to work on the full notebook without worrying about cells ordering like with a classical python script. When the script is ready, it is then possible to switch to the notebook view with its nice presentation features.

Comment: Perhaps, you had been working on a specially set up system where it was possible to open a `.py` file as a notebook and work on it. That isn't part of vanila Jupyter under the classic notebook interface. Isn't even an option under `Open with ..` in JupyterLab. If you install Jupytext you can do something along those lines in JupyterLab. For example, if you launch sessions from [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/pdbsum-binder/main), you'll see that ability works if you create a Python file and right-click on it in the file browser & use `Open with...`.

Comment: I couldn't refer you to the `launch JupyterLab` button from [Jupytext itself](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#readme) because the launcher for JupyterLab is [currently broken there](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/issues/989). Somebody asked for the ability to use Jupytext to allow that to  be integrated into Pycharm [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008152700-jupytext-support-of-pycharm-s-jupyter-notebook-plugin-). You may want to add you voice [there](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-951).

Comment: Thank you very much.
You are completely right. I installed jupytext and this is what allows me to save ipynb as py and then work on it.

Answer (score 0):

we did this when creating dash apps, you make the .py file upload and refer to it by way of importing as we do with regular python libraries